# Hibernate Persistencebag remove element from list

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, arraylist

I have two entities:

the first one:

```
    @Entity
    public class A{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", targetEntity = B.class, ...)
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        private List<B> b;

getter and setter

    }
```

and the second one:

```
@Entity
public class B{

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class, ...)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId",...)
    private A a;
```

now i read the data from the database and i want to remove some elements:

```
List<B> bList = a.getB();
for(B b: bList)
    if(some condiction)
      bList.remove(b)
```

why i can't?
why is bList a persistanceBag and not an ArrayList?
How can remove items from bList?
why can i see only one item in the debug modus?

Thanks
Chees

Comment: Are you shipping the A object to somewhere else outside of the hibernate transaction context? A PersistenceBag exception does usually mean that the object is not managed anymore by hibernate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate uses a proxy list to implement LAZY initialization and intercept any changes happening on the list, that's why it replaces the `ArrayList` with its own `PersistenceBag` implementation.

Simply add orphan-removal to your one-to-many association:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", targetEntity = B.class, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then remove the element from the list:

```
B toBeRemoved = ...;
a.b.remove(toBeRemoved);
toBeRemoved.a = null;
```

Comment: i got an PersistenceBag with many items but when i try to remove some one, i got this exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
 at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:789)

Comment: That's because you remove elements from the list you are currently iterating